# Multistage YAML pipeline to have seperate stage without dependencies

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps, I am using a Multistage YAML pipeline for Build and deployment. The screenshot shows the current pipeline setup. I wish to have sandbox1 separately without dependency on Build.

```
trigger: none
pr: none
stages:
- stage: 'Build'
  jobs:
  - job: 'Build'
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
        echo "Hello Testing"
- stage: 'Sandbox'
  jobs:
  - job: 'Sandbox'
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
        echo "Hello Testing"
- stage: 'DEV'
  jobs:
  - job: 'DEV'
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
        echo "Hello Testing"
- stage: 'QA'
  dependsOn: ['DEV','DEV1']
  jobs:
  - job: 'QA'
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
        echo "Hello Testing"
- stage: 'PROD'
  jobs:
  - job: 'DEV'
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
        echo "Hello Testing"
- stage: 'sandbox1'
  dependsOn: 'Build'
  jobs:
  - job: 'DEV1'
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
        echo "Hello Testing"
- stage: 'DEV1'
  jobs:
  - job: 'DEV1'
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
        echo "Hello Testing"
```

This is the pipeline structure I wish to have:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj2L6.png]
I have added the sample YAML code

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you share the yaml that you are using? Would create a second pipeline be an option?

Comment: @LucasGolven I have added a sample code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for confusion. I missed a feature. Your requirement is able to be achieved, just make the `dependsOn` empty. Check the sample below:

```
- stage: 'sandbox1'
  dependsOn: []    # this removes the implicit dependency on previous stage and causes this to run in parallel
```

[image]

Comment: But this option is available in classic Release Definition!! Whether we will get this option multistage YAML pipeline in future??

Comment: @Sar Sorry for confusion. I missed a feature. Your requirement is able to be achieved. Check my updated reply.